# Form validation error, input filed should highlight when error comes

Tags: angularjs, angular-forms

I have the following HTML code, where if my field is entered some value and erased, I am getting my field highlighted with red and get error message, mobile number is required. But if I type alphabet, I am getting error message, only numbers but the input box is not highlighted as red.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': ((submitted || cform.ccode1.$dirty || cform.submitted) && cform.ccode1.$invalid) || ((submitted || cform.mobile1.$dirty || cform.submitted) && cform.mobile1.$invalid) }" class="help-block">

    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon" style="width:25%;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" placeholder="Code" ng-model="model.ccode1" name="ccode1" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"
                readdonly required>

        </div>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobile1" ng-model="model.mobile1" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"
            min-length="2 " required>

    </div>
    <span ng-show="cform.ccode1.$dirty && cform.ccode1.$error.required" class="help-block">Code is required</span>
    <span ng-show="cform.mobile1.$dirty && cform.mobile1.$error.required" class="help-block1">Mobile number is required</span>
    <span ng-show="cform.ccode1.$dirty && cform.ccode1.$error.pattern" class="help-block">
        Must contain only numbers </span>
    <span ng-show="cform.mobile1.$dirty && cform.mobile1.$error.pattern" class="help-block1">
        Must contain only numbers </span>

</div>
```

[image: when field is empty and cleared]

[image: when alphabet entered]

Comment: Do you want to allow only number?

Comment: only numbers , and my input box should be highlighted as red , if it is wrong , like given in the image I mentioned

Comment: You can set ng-class in your input field and have some condition

Comment: I given that for pattern , but it doesnt work

Comment: ng-class="cform.mobile1.$dirty && cform.mobile1.$error.pattern ? 'error' : ''" Try to add this in your input field

.error{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

Comment: I tried this , only for first character it works.second character it stop hughlighting

Comment: For each time status is get changing that's the problem. Or is that ok to allow user to enter only numbers

Comment: yes , but incase we needed for only text and numbers. ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WJeRmL try this.. Here It will allow user to enter only number if you want to allow text also u can change

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put a directive to have only numbers like :

```
app.directive('uiNumber', [function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl, $filter, $parse) {
        element.mask("99999");

          }
       }
 }]);
```

---

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile" name="mobile1" ng-model="model.mobile1" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/"
        min-length="2 " required ui-number>
```

You just need to add **mask.js** to your project :http://bguzmanrio.github.io/maskjs/

hope this help